# Use LOOP for inserts?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4

I am using PostgreSQL 9.4.5 and I am new to PL/pgSQL.
I need to insert a message record for every user in the `users` table.

Something like this:

```
  user_id = SELECT id from users;

  FOR i in user_id
    INSERT INTO "messages" ("sender_id", "receiver_id", "content", 
    "hashed_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (1,i,
    "Message text here",(SELECT concat(md5(random()::text),
    md5(random()::text))),'2016-04-04 20:30:32','2016-04-04 20:30:32')';
  END
```

How to get this right?

Comment: PL/SQL is programming language used in Oracle db. Postgres has PL/pgSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO "messages" ("sender_id", "receiver_id", "content",  "hashed_id", "created_at", "updated_at") 
    SELECT 1, id, 'Message text here',
           concat(md5(random()::text), md5(random()::text)),
           '2016-04-04 20:30:32','2016-04-04 20:30:32'
    FROM users;
```

Note:  You don't need the subselect for the `concat()`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! That helped me a lot!